# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

I'm running this command through Jenkins file:
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean package"

and getting this error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project automation: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 ->

**When I'm running this command locally (using my IntelliJ terminal) it works as should!!
mvn version is 3.6.0 in both Jenkins server and my computer**

my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ssl-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central-1</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central-2</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.12</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Java 6 = JAX-B Version 2.0   -->
        <!-- Java 7 = JAX-B Version 2.2.3 -->
        <!-- Java 8 = JAX-B Version 2.2.8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>7.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev516-1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>test_listener.TestListener</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <kobi>old</kobi>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                    <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: 1. You configured your maven compiler plugin twice which is not sensible. 2. You once configured Java 8 and once Java 10. What do you want? Notice that Java 10 should not be used any more, either use Java 8, 11 or the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my POM (in my post). it is still not working for me. " Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project automation: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 ->"

Comment: you should run maven goal with java 11. For this you should set JAVA_HOME and JAVACMD variables. for example export JAVACMD=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

Comment: Where should I set these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the java version that my Jenkins server used (he used JAVA7 and I'm using JAVA 11)